# How to track different users with Google Analytics and Google Tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager, drupal-8

I have a website that has a number of different user types examples managers, employees, and supervisors. I was wondering how to track them in Google Analytics. Is there a way in Google tag manager to segment these users? or will I have fire something in the javascript code?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I disagree, while the problem may be a webmaster question its solution is inherently a coding problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using tracking pixels? You can specify which pixel runs based on the user using a switch case statement and then see it in your dashboard.

```
switch(userType) {
  case 'Manager':
    //pixel 1
  break;
  case 'employee':
    //pixel 2
  break;
  case 'supervisor':
    //pixel 3
  break;
}
```

Comment: No I haven't how to set that up? sorry I'm new to analytics

Comment: @GastonVelarde here is a tutorial https://hawkemedia.com/blog/how-to-place-a-google-analytics-pixel

Answer (score 0):

If you can recognize them while browsing, you can pass it with pageview or event to Google Analytics as custom dimension at user level. The value can be just *managers*, *employees* or *supervisors* based on who accesses.